# The maximal connected compact submanifold of $O(n)$

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups

Suppose that $S$ is a connected compact embedded submanifold of $O(n)$ with dimension equal to $O(n)$, is it true that $S$ has to be a component of $O(n)$?

My guess is that it should be true, but I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Submanifolds of the same dimension must be open. Since it's open, closed and connected, it must be a component. There's nothing special about $O(n)$ here.